# Android - Live Wallpaper + Activity "Launcher does not have the permission to launch Intent"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've created live wallpaper which is working. Then, I tried to add main activity with config, but there's an "Launcher does not have the permission to launch Intent" error when I click on a icon on programs list.

```
ERROR/Launcher(8246): Launcher does not have the permission to launch Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.revicostudio.neonshiftwallpaper/.ConfigActivity }. Make sure to create a MAIN intent-filter for the corresponding activity or use the exported attribute for this activity. tag=ApplicationInfo(title=Neon Shift Wallpaper) intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.revicostudio.neonshiftwallpaper/.ConfigActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.revicostudio.neonshiftwallpaper/.ConfigActivity } from ProcessRecord{41ea3da8 8246:com.android.launcher/u0a10035} (pid=8246, uid=10035) not exported from uid 10139
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.revicostudio.neonshiftwallpaper"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"
            android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper">
    </uses-feature>

    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!--  Live Wallpaper Service -->
        <service android:name=".MainService"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:description="@string/wallpaper_description">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                       android:resource="@xml/wallpaper"/>
        </service>

        <activity
                android:name=".ConfigActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:exported="true"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.revicostudio.neonshiftwallpaper.WallpaperPreferences"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because when you add a shortcut to an app on your home screen, the launcher keeps it's own copy of the original intent from your manifest, maybe formatted as a String rather than an actual Java object.

So after you change the intent by modifying the filter or the class it points to, you end up with a dead shortcut.

If this is what happened to you, it should work fine if you try to launch it from the app drawer. You can just delete the shortcut from your home screen and add it again, and the new shortcut should work.

This can happen to your users if you modify the class name of the main activity in between releases.